# Bioinformatics: How do a contrast Limma with 3 groups (case/control, age and gender)

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor, limma

I'm a student and I have doubts about how use **Limma** to contrast the differential gene expression evaluating my three variables: *disease (case/control), gender(male/female) and age*.

My data is like this: (three columns with the gender, age and the disease)

> head(pData(gse))

**Data Here:**

[image]

I know build my experiment over my variable disease:

```
    design= model.matrix(~ pData(gse)[,"disease"])
    colnames(design)= c("control", "case")

    fit= lmFit(gse, fesign)
    fit1= eBayes(fit)

    topTable(fit1, coef=2, adjust="BH", number= as.numeric(dim(gse)[1]))
```

But, **How I can do a contrast Limma with my 3 variables?  Thank for your help!**

```
age= pData(gse)[,"age"]
gender= pData(gse)[,"gender"]
disease= pData(gse)[,"disease"]

age.group= ifelse(age>40,"over40", "under40")

design = model.matrix(~0 + disease + gender + gender:age)

contr.matrix <- makeContrasts(  **???**
```